# phpinfo reports no value for PDO MySQL driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As per the title I'm having problems with PHP 5.2.10 and getting PDO MySQL to be recognised.

My configure command contains `'--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr'`

and the `pdo_mysql.so` file is available in the folder indicated by `extension_dir` variable, I've added

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

to php.ini and there are ini files in the `php.d` folder for the pdo drivers, but still phpinfo reports the PDO support is enabled but the drivers value is set to `no value`.

I'm on Centos with Nginx, PHP 5.2.10

I'm kinda stuck, your help would be appreciated

Comment: is php-pdo installed?

Comment: Where is the PHP binary from? From your systems package manager?

Comment: Ah, just done a pecl install pdo_mysql and got...

checking for mysql_query in -lmysqlclient... no
configure: error: mysql_query missing!?

Comment: @hakre not sure where it's from. doing yum list installed | grep pdo
returns php-pdo.i386 5.2.10-1.el5.centos installed

Comment: yum is the package manager. can you tell for the PHP itself as well?

Comment: not sure how php was install, any tips?